# undefined method `order' for "1":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my landing_pages "show" page, I'm trying to show the leads that came in via that page and sort them via their "score".

My landing_page model has:

```
has_many :page_leads
```

My page_lead model has:

```
belongs_to :landing_page
```

In my index method within my page_leads controller, I have this, which works:

```
def index
    @page_leads = PageLead.order(score: :desc)
end
```

I try to duplicate this in the landing_pages controller for the show method. Here is what I have:

```
def show
    @landingpage = LandingPage.find(params[:id]).order(score: :desc)
end
```

When I try to go to the "Show" page, I get an error "undefined method `order' for "1":String". How can I get this to work?

My show page has the following code:

```
<tbody>
    <% @landingpage.page_leads.each do |page_lead| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= page_lead.fname %></td>
        <td><%= page_lead.lname %></td>
        <td><%= page_lead.score %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: What is the type of the "score" field?

Comment: It could be `@landingpage = LandingPage.find(params[:id])` and `@some_object = @landingpage.page_leades.order(score: :desc)`.

Comment: what get passed to "id" params?

Answer (score 0):

It is just:

```
def show
  @landingpage = LandingPage.find(params[:id])
end
```

Cause `find` returns the LandingPage with `id == params[:id]`. No need to sort a single item.

Comment: It's actually returning a list of all of the page_leads associated to that landing page. I need to sort it so the page_leads with the highest score are at the top.

Comment: @ScottS. Did you override ActiveRecord's `find` method? Please double check, because if zou did not than `LandingPage.find(params[:id])` will return a single LandingPage and not a list of PageLeads. There is nothing in your show method that comes even close to PageLeads.

Answer (score 0):

find returns an array or records if the params[:id] is an array.. the order can't be applied to the array, because order isn't part of the array class.

If params[:id] is a single element then the find returns the record.  Again order doesn't apply, because it's just one record not a container of records..

If you want an sorted list then use 
   LandingPage.where(id: params[:id]).order

But since this is in the show I suspect you want the single item... As spickermann said drop the order

```
 LandingPage.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Actually I do want the page to show the list of the page_leads so @landingpage = LandingPage.where(id: params[:id]).order(score: :desc) would make sense. However, when I do that I get an error on my "Show" page. I've added that code above. The error is: NoMethodError in LandingPages#show with undefined method `page_leads'. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort Page Leads, you would do something like

```rb
def show
    @landingpage = LandingPage.find(params[:id])
    @page_leads = @landingpage.page_leads.order(score: :desc)
end
```

As @spickermann mentioned, `.find()` only returns one model instance. You can't order this using ActiveRecord query methods.

If you want to order the page leads, you have to call `.order` on the set of page_leads that belong to the landing page

Comment: I tried the above and it's still not sorting the page_leads.

Comment: @ScottS. `@landingpage.page_leads` will not be sorted, only `@page_leads`. Make sure you use that